# how to make sweet potato fries crunchy?

Tags: frying, deep-frying, texture, french-fries, sweet-potatoes

I wanted to make sweet potato fries but it was very disappointing and not crunchy at all.

I put the first batch in a medium-heat oil and left them for a while, they got out all soggy. I turned up the heat for the second batch, it got a bit better but still way below my crunch expectations. I even tried to put the first batch back in the hot oil, remembering that good Belgian potato fries should go in the oil twice, but I just managed to burn them.

Do you know what I did wrong? Is it because of an excess of humidity? They were pretty dry already when I put them in the oil.

I've read that they should be coated in flour before, does that work? I don't see how it would stick well to the sweet potatoes, aren't them too dry for that?

Comment: We have a duplicate question on this, though it doesn't provide a satisfactory answer.  In my opinion, you can't make sweet potato fries crunchy unless you coat them with a batter or crust of some sort.  They don't behave the same as regular white potatoes.

Comment: Welcome to SA, Sarah!  I totally agree with moscafj, here, but not posting an answer since I don't have a recipe I've tested.

Comment: FWIW, we have three other questions just like this one, all without good/accepted answers.  As such, please do NOT close Sarah's question ... calling it a duplicate of a question without an answer isn't helpful.

Comment: @FuzzyChef if we have three old questions, it would be best to close two of them as a duplicate of the third. Can you please link the two others in a comment to the best or oldest question so we can close the proliferation? And I get why you call it "not helpful" but having multiple open questions without an answer is even less helpful - longer answer on your meta question.

Comment: Yes I saw the other post but it was old and about using a different type of fryer, so I just wanted to check if users since then might have an answer that would be relevant to me. Sorry if the multiple questions made it more difficult @rumtscho, I'm a new user :) Next time I'll phrase my post differently to have only one question.

Comment: Sarah: not a problem, this is a reviewer/moderator discussion.  We actually don't often get repeats of good questions that don't have good answers this way.  Perfectly OK for your having asked it.

Comment: Here's the other duplicates: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/62078/does-the-par-boiling-first-then-frying-work-for-sweet-potatoes-as-well, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/66233/baked-sweet-potato-french-fries-chips-too-soft-how-to-crispen, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/91279/standard-way-to-make-crispy-sweet-potato-fries

None of these have accepted answers, and of the few answers that are there, pretty much all are speculative ... none have sources or personal experience to indicate that they actually work.